# Meaning of 'Tends' $\rightarrow$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question

Meaning of 'Tends' $\rightarrow$.

I found a definition of tends in the book Higher Algebra by Barnard and Child and I am being obtuse.

> **"Definition: To say that x tends to zero is to say that x varies in such a way that its numerical value becomes and remains less than any positive number that we may choose, no matter how small."**

Comment on the definition stated and explain the fact.

Comment: See definition of limit.  Also, I found it funny that back "before 1923" this kind of thing was called "higher algebra."  Nowadays, works by Lurie come to mind.

Comment: See [epsilon-delta def of limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) : saying that e.g. a function $f(x)$ has limit $L$ for $x \to 0$ (usually said "when $x$ *tends to* $0$") must be undestood that "whatever value ($\epsilon$) we choose for the interval $L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon$ we can always find an interval $0-\delta,0+\delta$ such that all the values of $f(x)$ for the point inside this interval will "fall inside" the previous one". 1/2

Comment: This def "formalize" the intuitive idea that "going indefinitely near" to $0$ on the $x$-axis will cause the value of $f(x)$ to "approach" the limit-value $L$.

Comment: I usually consider the notion $x \to a$ as the family of sequences that converge to $a$ (or more abstractly, the family of neighborhood filter bases at $a$.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One need not dwell on the "definition" of the separate meaning of a symbol in, especially, mathematics.

The symbol $dx$ appearing in an integral does not have meaning in itself, unless one talks about differential forms.
In the same token,
the symbol "$\to$" is context-determined, that is to say, writing "$\to$" alone does not say any concrete thing. To exemplify this, just recall that we use "$\to$" both in the context of specifying functions and that of limits.

The best way, to me, to "define" the phrase "$x \to a$" in a context involving limits is to say that it is simply a suggestive, mnemonic abbreviation for rigorous analytic language. 
For example, we say "$f(x) \to l$ as $x \to a$" to mean "for every $\varepsilon > 0, \cdots$ $|f(x) - l| < \varepsilon \cdots $

Answer (score 0):

Before getting into the formal definition of tends to and a limit, we can try to see what happens when we bring x arbitrarily close to a, i.e. as $x \to a$.

Consider a simple function $f(x) = (x^2 - 1)/(x - 1)$.

If we try to work out the value of $f(x)$ at $x = 1$, we get $0/0$ which is indeterminate.

What we can do though, is try to 'approach' 1.

$f(0.5) = 1.5$

Well, we are quite far, let's move closer.

$f(0.9) = 1.9$

Good, but not close enough for me.

$f(0.99) = 1.99$

Well, that looks better.

$f(0.999) = 1.999$

Now we're getting somewhere.

This can go on and on and I can get the value of $f(x)$ arbitrarily close 2.

$f(0.9999) = 1.9999$

$f(0.99999) = 1.99999$

We cannot say what $f(x)$ is when $x = 1$. But we see that $f(x)$ is getting closer and closer to $2$ as $x \to 1$. This is formally written as

$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 2$

The limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to 1$ is $2$.